# SwiftTutorialのCreate Table Viewにて、セルが表示されないため困っています。

Tags: swift

質問

SwiftTutorialのCreate Table Viewにて、セルが表示されるようにしたい。

URL

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH8-SW1

サンプルプロジェクトに関して　Githubなどでよいのでしょうか？？

https://github.com/tommottom/FoodTracker

現状行った事。

・MealTableViewCell.swiftファイルを生成
・TableViewControllerをMain.Stroyboardに配置した。
・TableViewCellのReuseIdentifierに「MealTableViewCell」を設定
・TableViewCellのClassから「MealTableViewCell」 を選択する。
・Stroyboard EnrtyPointは、TableViewControllerを指定しています。

結果

真っ白なページが表示されます。

解決方法1

TableViewController.swiftファイルを生成して、そこにセクションがいくつで、TableViewがいくつで、というのを書き込めば良いのかなと考えましたが、表示されません。

Comment: 「SwiftTutorialのCreate Table View」のリンクを貼ってください。それと、サンプルコードの対象Swiftバージョンと、あなたが現在お使いのXcodeのバージョン情報も必要です。

Comment: ソースコードを貼るか、サンプルプロジェクトをどこかにアップロードして見れるようにする必要があるかと思います。現状の説明では回答できません。

Comment: リンク先、拝見しました。ざっくりと見た段階ですが、やはり、あなたがチュートリアルどおりに作業していない、なにかがあるんだろうという印象を持っています。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
チュートリアル自体にミスがあったりもするので、もしかしたらと考えていましたが、もう一度チュートリアルをしっかりと見てみたいと考えます。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

最後のほうの「Load Initial Data」で、セルを表示するためのUITableViewControllerを追加します。

そのため、それまでは必要なコードが記述されていないため、いつまでたっても真っ白です。
なので、参考画像を貼っているのだと思います。(わかりづらい)
初心者の方には辛いですね。。